# Trying to pass data to View (contains ListView) and set it as content

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a List of strings in my main page,
which I want to pass to another view. The attribute,
to whom I writing to has a binding. Essentially it's
the ItemSource of the ListView.

I tried additionally to List, both string[] and ObservableCollection as data storage
for Projects, since the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding) recommends to use it.

Trying to use the -element from MyView.xaml in MainPage.xaml works like charm.

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
Content = new MyView { Projects = MyProjects };
```

**MyView.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MyView : ContentView
{
    private List<string> _projects;
    public List<string> Projects
    {
        get => _projects; 
        set
        {
            _projects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Projects));
        }
    }
    //public string[] Test = new string[] { "Test", "Hallo", "Welt" };
    public MyView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**MyView.xaml:**

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="p_lstView" RowHeight="160" SeparatorColor="DodgerBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding}"></Label>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with the `BindingContext` on the `ListView.ItemSource`. The current context is on the MainPage.

You need to change:

```
<ListView BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="p_lstView" RowHeight="160" SeparatorColor="DodgerBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding Content.Projects}">
```

Alternative, you can set the `BindingContext` in the `MyView` constrctor.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `BindingContext` then the binding will work:

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = this;
}
```